# INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY question

Tags: mysql

i have a table '**tag_article_assoc**' with [tagId,articleId] fields. i want to 
insert new tags for a specific article (lets say articleId=23) but skip records already in db.
i am not sure on the right syntax, any ideas?

```
INSERT INTO wd_article_tag_assoc (tagId,articleId) VALUES ('$upTag','23') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...
```

thanks
S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have the tagId,articleId both as primary key in your database

```
INSERT INTO wd_article_tag_assoc (tagId,articleId) VALUES ('$upTag','23') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tagId=$upTag
```

You are welcome to read
["INSERT IGNORE" vs "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update)

Comment: you are right ntan. only the one was primary. thanks for the tip!

Comment: you are welcome.I keep forgetting my too but with my new MAC i will try too do better

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO wd_article_tag_assoc (tagId,articleId) VALUES ('$upTag','23')
```

Comment: ok, thats fine, but i would like to check out the "on duplicate syntax"

Comment: Is INSERT IGNORE doing not what you want?

Comment: i do not think this is working orsol. there are still duplicates created.